# React JS - Countdown timer using Moment.js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, countdown

I'm very new to React - so bear with my noob question. But I have a component I'm trying to display inside a button. I've tested the function in a fiddle and it works great, but for some reason this module is showing up blank when I test it.

(*using moment.js*)

Here's my files:

```
//countdown.js
import moment from 'moment';

const CountDownTimer = () => {
    var eventTime = '1626573600';
    var currentTime = (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)).toString();
    var leftTime = eventTime - currentTime;
    var duration = moment.duration(leftTime, 'seconds');
    var interval = 1000;

    function ShowTimer() {
        setInterval(function(){
            // Time Out check
            if (duration.asSeconds() <= 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                //window.location.reload(true); //#skip the cache and reload the page from the server
            }

            //Otherwise
            duration = moment.duration(duration.asSeconds() - 1, 'seconds');
            return (duration.days() + ' Days ' + duration.hours()+ ' Hours ' + duration.minutes()+ ' Minutes ' + duration.seconds() + ' Seconds');
        }, interval);
    }

    return (
        <span>{ShowTimer()}</span>
    )
}
export default CountDownTimer;
```

Here's the usage:

```
//Slider.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CountDownTimer from "../../scripts/countdown.js";

...
...
...


   <div className="div-buyNowBtn">            
      <button id="buyNowBtn" className="white-fill-bg btn-outline btn-lg">
         Sale Active in: <CountDownTimer/>
      </button>
   </div>
```

Comment: what does the console say? what does the terminal building the code say?

Comment: also, `ShowTimer` doesn't return anything here

Comment: @DerekPollard terminal says nothing. I see what you mean... the return is from the setInterval function. What would you do here?

Comment: Here, I'd probably update a state variable that contains duration, getting rid of the function `ShowTimer` entirely; then I'd create a setTimout ref that handles updating the duration state variable. My render function would be actually displaying the countdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The issue

The issue with the original code is that `ShowTimer` was returning nothing, essentially meaning your return value was "void"

### The solution

I decided to clean up the function a bit and make it more performant. Instead of having unnecessary renders occur due to un-tracked internal functions (`ShowTimer`) I decided to extract the logic outside of the component that stayed constant (`calculateDuration`).

Then, using `useEffect`, I started my timer and made sure to update a new state variable called `duration`.

Finally, to ensure we properly update, and kill the timer whenever the component unmounts /  or the event time changes, I make sure to clearInterval. This should prevent any memory leaks from occurring.

#### All wrapped up with a nice bow:

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

const calculateDuration = eventTime => moment.duration(Math.max(eventTime - (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)), 0), 'seconds');

function Countdown({ eventTime, interval }) {
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(calculateDuration(eventTime));
  const timerRef = useRef(0);
  const timerCallback = useCallback(() => {
    setDuration(calculateDuration(eventTime));
  }, [eventTime])

  useEffect(() => {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(timerCallback, interval);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    }
  }, [eventTime]);

  return (
    <div>
      {duration.days()} Days {duration.hours()} Hours {duration.minutes()} Minutes {duration.seconds()} Seconds
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Countdown eventTime={1626573600} interval={1000} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DerekPollard I was able to do the following and it solved the issue. Everything works great now.

```
import moment from 'moment';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const CountDownTimer = () => {
    

    const calculateTimeLeft = () => {
        let eventTime = '1626573600';
        let currentTime = (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)).toString();
        let leftTime = eventTime - currentTime;
        let duration = moment.duration(leftTime, 'seconds');
        let interval = 1000;
        if (duration.asSeconds() <= 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            //window.location.reload(true); //#skip the cache and reload the page from the server
        }
        duration = moment.duration(duration.asSeconds() - 1, 'seconds');
        return (duration.days() + ' Days ' + duration.hours()+ ' Hours ' + duration.minutes()+ ' Minutes ' + duration.seconds() + ' Seconds');
    }

    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(calculateTimeLeft());

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
        },1000);
    });
   

    return (
        <span>{timeLeft}</span>
    )
}
export default CountDownTimer;
```

Comment: Love seeing users come up with their own solutions from my explanations! I'll post my working solution as well for more information